# Need help making Console.Writeline block more efficent with loops

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

Hey i just made a small console application that writes out the jobs someone needs to apply for , the location and the contact method as like a small exercise to do.
Looking at my code it seems that constantly writing out the Console.WriteLine statement is very in-efficient considering i made functions to assist in be efficient.

I was thinking the best way to accomplish this would be to use a loop but im not sure how to make it loop each time with a different variable (e.g. phn1, phn2 variables)

Thanks guys !

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PlacestoApplyfor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Displays the actual program in descending order.
            //Used functions as a faster method to change variable names on the fly
            //Whilst keeping its format clean and in descending order 
            Console.WriteLine("--Name of Places--");
            ApplyFor("EdwayApps" ,"Appxperts","Genie App Studio","Appster");
            Console.WriteLine("--Name of Locations--");
            LocationsInOrder("3/424 St kilda", "101/27 Little Collins St", "Contact Online only", "2/377 LonsDale ST");
            Console.WriteLine("--Companies Numbers-- ");
            PhoneNumbers(043990976,1300939225,0421336722,1800709291);
        }

        static void ApplyFor(string num1, string num2, string num3, string num4) {
        //Literally just the job names 
        Console.WriteLine(num1);
        Console.WriteLine(num2);
        Console.WriteLine(num3);
        Console.WriteLine(num4);
        }

        // Job Locations

        static void LocationsInOrder(string loc1, string loc2, string loc3, string loc4) {
        Console.WriteLine(loc1);
        Console.WriteLine(loc2);
        Console.WriteLine(loc3);
        Console.WriteLine(loc4);
        }

        //Contact - references

        static void PhoneNumbers(int phn1, int phn2, int phn3, int phn4) {
        Console.WriteLine(phn1);
        Console.WriteLine(phn2);
        Console.WriteLine(phn3);
        Console.WriteLine(phn4);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you indenting each line in your methods further and further?

Comment: When you pass your phone number as int `0421336722` you are loosing leading zero. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Console.WriteLine() is pretty expensive, the underlying process interop with the conhost.exe process that actually owns the console window isn't very efficient.  It is however still far, **far** faster than the user's eyes.  Crazily scrolling text in a console window is just completely unusable UI.  You'll have to address that basic issue instead, now you completely don't care about Console.WriteLine() anymore.

Comment: Sorry im really new to programming , i wasnt aware of either and idk man it looked cool.

Answer (score 4):

The [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword is your friend:

```
static void PhoneNumbers(params int[] phn) 
{
    foreach(var num in phn)
        Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

You can then just do:

```
PhoneNumbers(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Or even pass in an array:

```
PhoneNumbers(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
```

Comment: Sorry Im still new to programming and dont fully quite understand what you mean , but i will have a crack at it. Do you mean put an array instead of the PhoneNumbers function ? or do i place that inside the function ? 
Please let me know if im on the right track

Comment: @keanu.b It's both an array and syntactic sugar. It allows you to pass a variable number of parameters (of the same type) to the method, or you can pass an array. Internally you just treat the parameter like you would an array in either case.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing so much console.writeline() 
Instead of that write the following Code

> In the class

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--Name of Places--");
        ApplyFor("EdwayApps", "Appxperts", "Genie App Studio", "Appster");
        Console.WriteLine("--Name of Locations--");
        LocationsInOrder("3/424 St kilda", "101/27 Little Collins St", "Contact Online only", "2/377 LonsDale ST");
        Console.WriteLine("--Companies Numbers-- ");
        PhoneNumbers(043990976, 1300939225, 0421336722, 1800709291);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void ApplyFor(string num1, string num2, string num3, string num4)
    {
        //Literally just the job names 
        Console.WriteLine(num1 + "\n"+num2 + "\n" + num3 + "\n " + num4);
    }
    // Job Locations
    static void LocationsInOrder(string loc1, string loc2, string loc3, string loc4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(loc1 + "\n" + loc2 + "\n" + loc3 + "\n " + loc4);
    }
    //Contact - references
    static void PhoneNumbers(int phn1, int phn2, int phn3, int phn4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(phn1 + "\n" + phn2 + "\n" + phn3 + "\n " + phn4 +"\n");
    }
```

Comment: That looks so much better , sorry im new to programming and i forgot how to make a new line

Comment: Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You could do with just one function to write all your lines, and configure the separator for newline "\n" or ", " for one line with comma separated values. You could even add the "topic" as the first parameter of your print function so it will get expanded within the "-- Topic --" symbols.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Displays the actual program in descending order.
    //Used functions as a faster method to change variable names on the fly
    //Whilst keeping its format clean and in descending order 
    Print("Name of Places", "EdwayApps", "Appxperts", "Genie App Studio", "Appster");
    Print("Name of Locations", "3/424 St kilda", "101/27 Little Collins St", "Contact Online only", "2/377 LonsDale ST");
    Print("Companies Numbers", 043990976, 1300939225, 0421336722, 1800709291);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void Print(string topic, params object[] array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-- {0} -- \n\n  {1}\n", topic, string.Join("\n  ", array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/w5zay9db.aspx) is cool like Lloyd said, but if your trying to optimize Console.WriteLine(), lets not make a loop calling .WriteLine over and over for that. Take a look at [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh1dzhdx(v=vs.110).aspx) and [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) methods

```
static void PhoneNumbers(params int[] phn) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, phn));
}
```

Same thing just space separated values, on one line

```
static void PhoneNumbers(params int[] phn) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", phn));
}
```

or if you want to write all those values in one line with a fixed number of values just do this

```
static void PhoneNumbers(params int[] phn) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", phn));
}
```

Comment: So if i format the phone number values in will change it into string form and then list it ? Well like write it

Comment: Oh wait so if inside the console.writeline("", phn ) i can add the name of the place and then it will add the variable after it ?

Comment: Take a look at that documentation... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh1dzhdx(v=vs.110).aspx basically String.Format allows you to put place holders in a string for where you want to print your object. In your case you have lets say an array of 4 integers. {0} will be the location of the first integer in that array, and {1} will be the location of the second so on... it's similar to doing array[0]+", " + array[1] + ", " + array[2] + ", " + array[3] you can also do some additional formatting using that, or String.Concat exists as well

Comment: Ah yes i understand , took me some time , thanks man , i will try it out